# Firebase: How to use child changed with tables?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not sure how `child_changed` can be used with tables. `child_added` will work in populating the table but when some change in data occurs, then how to identify which row needs to be updated?

Official documentation suggests `child_added` to be used with `child_changed` and `child_removed` but I'm not sure how the latter 2 will work.

> The child_changed event is triggered any time a child node is modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child node. It is typically used in conjunction with the child_added and child_removed events to respond to changes to a list of items. The snapshot passed to the event listener contains the updated data for the child.

All I can think of is storing an ID along with the row data, then listening for changes, then getting the ID stored and changing the row data accordingly.

Comment: That is indeed a common way of handling lists of Firebase data: keep the id associated with the row and update/move/remove when you receive the relevant child_ event. Are you having problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me then you might use data ID's as keys in your data. EG:

{
  "customers":
    {
      "62562":
        {
           "name": "Joe blogs"
        }
    }
}

```
firebase.database().ref('/customers/62562').on('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

The above code gives you changes to the data contained in '/customers/62562' but you you won't know where it is from. You need to look at the reference of the snapshot if you wish to know the customerId like:

```
var customerId = snapShot.ref.key         returns '62562'
```

You can even go further up the branch and find out which branch holds this customer

```
var parentName = snapShot.ref.parent.key         returns 'customer'
```